# Json play libs parse() cannot resolve simple parse

Tags: json, scala, parsing, playframework

I have the code below and get a compile time error on `Json.parse` saying `cannot resolve symbol parse`. I'm passing in an `eventData` of type `String`, and `parse()` takes a string, so why is it not working?

```
override def recordEvent(customerId: String, eventType: String, eventData: String, eventMetadata: String, profileUpdate: ProfileUpdate): Future[AvroCustomer] = {

      val id = UUID.fromString(customerId)
      val updates: Option[ProfileUpdateData] = Option(profileUpdate).map(parseUpdates)

      val eventData = Json.parse(eventData)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, despite my specifying the value of the `val eventData` I'm declaring, the fact that the parameter `eventData` and the declared `val eventData` are named the same, that was causing an error.